# Ubuntu 16.04 unity: No text is shown in many windows

Tags: 16.04, unity, hibernate, window-manager

I hibernated my laptop a few times.

I closed the lid and reopened it.

This is what happened:

[image: Empty Terminal]

I cannot see anything but I can enter commands.

This is the `nautilus` window:

[image: Empty nautilus window]

How can I fix this problem without any reboot, logout or anything that leads closing the currently open application?

I welcome any terminal command.

Comment: Have you tried a clean reboot or shut down and back on? Hibernate on many devices isn't well supported on Linux...

Comment: @Zanna, If I reboot or `unity --replace`, I am sure the problem will be solved. But, I do not want killing the currently open applications.

Comment: I am sure this problem happens to others too. I has happened to me several times. I am curious how to fix it. I cannot reproduce this problem often. If you know the solution, please suggest me ASAP before I restart and loose the chance to verify if your method works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959) with Ubuntu 16.04. One possible fix seems to be upgrading to kernel 4.8 or higher. You can attempt to update your current kernel by running the command:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: It may require a reboot once after the new kernel is installed, but the fix (if it works) should be permanent.